# Criteria Query fetches all the related entities if the where clause is not specified

Tags: java, jpa, h2, criteria-api

I am trying to run a simple criteria Query. However, the output shows 4 queries being executed instead of a single query which is quite unexpected.

I am wondering, have I missed any constraints in the Domain model or Criteria Query.

Below is the domain model.

[image]

**Student**

```
    @Entity
    public class Student {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private Long id;

      @Column(nullable = false)
      private String name;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy="student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private Passport passport;

    ...
    }
```

**Passport**

```
@Entity
public class Passport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String number;

    @OneToOne
    private Student student;

}
```

I have used the below criteria query to fetch the student records. 
I would also like to mention few points about the relationship mapping.

- `@ManyToMany` and `@OneToMany` relationship is by default `Lazy`Load.
- I have explicitly set `@OneToOne` as `Lazy` load.

  ```
  CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Student> cq = builder.createQuery(Student.class);
  Root<Student> root = cq.from(Student.class);
  cq.select(root);
  //cq.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), 10001L));
  List<Student> resultList = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
  resultList.forEach(s -> log.info("{}",s));
  ```

Following is the output:

```
    2019-01-30 15:34:40.883  INFO 13760 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Hibernate: 
        select
            student0_.id as id1_4_,
            student0_.name as name2_4_ 
        from
            student student0_
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.436 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_4_] : [BIGINT]) - [2001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.444 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name2_4_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Irshad]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.445 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_4_] : [BIGINT]) - [2002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.446 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name2_4_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Ahmad]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.446 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_4_] : [BIGINT]) - [2003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.446 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name2_4_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Sheikh]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.460 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.initgrep.jpademo.student.Student.addresses#2001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.460 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.initgrep.jpademo.student.Student.courses#2001]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            passport0_.id as id1_2_1_,
            passport0_.number as number2_2_1_,
            passport0_.student_id as student_3_2_1_,
            student1_.id as id1_4_0_,
            student1_.name as name2_4_0_ 
        from
            passport passport0_ 
        left outer join
            student student1_ 
                on passport0_.student_id=student1_.id 
        where
            passport0_.student_id=?
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.465 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.466 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_4_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [2001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.466 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_2_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [4001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.467 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([number2_2_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [E1001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.467 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([student_3_2_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [2001]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.475 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.initgrep.jpademo.student.Student.addresses#2002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.476 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.initgrep.jpademo.student.Student.courses#2002]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            passport0_.id as id1_2_1_,
            passport0_.number as number2_2_1_,
            passport0_.student_id as student_3_2_1_,
            student1_.id as id1_4_0_,
            student1_.name as name2_4_0_ 
        from
            passport passport0_ 
        left outer join
            student student1_ 
                on passport0_.student_id=student1_.id 
        where
            passport0_.student_id=?
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.476 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.477 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_4_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [2002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.477 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_2_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [4002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.477 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([number2_2_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [E1002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.478 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([student_3_2_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [2002]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.478 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.initgrep.jpademo.student.Student.addresses#2003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.478 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.initgrep.jpademo.student.Student.courses#2003]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            passport0_.id as id1_2_1_,
            passport0_.number as number2_2_1_,
            passport0_.student_id as student_3_2_1_,
            student1_.id as id1_4_0_,
            student1_.name as name2_4_0_ 
        from
            passport passport0_ 
        left outer join
            student student1_ 
                on passport0_.student_id=student1_.id 
        where
            passport0_.student_id=?
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.479 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.479 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_4_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [2003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.479 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_2_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [4003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.480 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([number2_2_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [E1003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.480 TRACE 13760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([student_3_2_1_] : [BIGINT]) - [2003]
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.480 DEBUG 13760 --- [           main] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsImpl         : HHH000117: HQL: select generatedAlias0 from Student as generatedAlias0, time: 61ms, rows: 3
    2019-01-30 15:34:41.484  INFO 13760 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
        170294 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
        0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
        **5107615 nanoseconds spent preparing 4 JDBC statements;
        5699493 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;**
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

I am assuming, the Criteria Query does not respect the declared `FetchType.LAZY` on the entity. Since `Student -> Passport` is a `1-1` relationship. It is fetched eagerly.

If I add the below where clause.

```
cq.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), 10001L))
```

It only fetches the student and no other relationships are fetched as verified by the below output.

```
        Hibernate: 
        select
            student0_.id as id1_4_,
            student0_.name as name2_4_ 
        from
            student student0_ 
        where
            student0_.id=10001
    2019-01-30 15:43:12.662 DEBUG 5964 --- [           main] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsImpl         : HHH000117: HQL: select generatedAlias0 from Student as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id=10001L, time: 22ms, rows: 0
    2019-01-30 15:43:12.665  INFO 5964 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
        169108 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
        0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
        4718825 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
        7554940 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

> UPDATE: Insert script.

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(id,name) VALUES (2001, 'Irshad');
INSERT INTO STUDENT(id,name) VALUES (2002, 'Ahmad');
INSERT INTO STUDENT(id,name) VALUES (2003, 'Sheikh');

INSERT INTO PASSPORT(id, number, student_id) VALUES (4001, 'E1001', 2001);
INSERT INTO PASSPORT(id, number, student_id) VALUES (4002, 'E1002', 2002);
INSERT INTO PASSPORT(id, number, student_id) VALUES (4003, 'E1003', 2003);
```

Comment: Just to be sure: it's not your `Student.toString()` method called by the logger that's causing the lazy relations to be loaded, right?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if it is due to `toString()`, it should not make a difference when using a `where` clause. Moreover, `toString()` implementation only displays `ID and NAME` of Student

Comment: The JPA specification say: "The LAZY strategy is 
a **hint** to the persistence provider runtime" (i.e. JPA 2.0, Chapter 11.1.37). Your JPA Implementation decides what the best way is.

Comment: it looks like you only have  3 Student records with ids 2001, 2002 and 2003 so when you look for student with id 10001, it won't find any and there is no point to load the Passport. try changing the id to 2003 in your where clause to see how many queries you get.

Comment: @RezaNasiri I have updated the question with the insert script. Each student have exactly one passport. I still ran with different IDs as suggested by you But it did not make any difference. Any other idea

Comment: can you provide the mapping you used for Student and Passport entities?

Comment: I have updated the entity definition in the Question.
I have found two workarounds till now:
1) Fetch the Passport. `root.fetch("passport", FetchType.INNER)`. It fetches the passports along with student and limits the query to only one. However, it does not serve the purpose. why fetch passport if it is not required.
2) Specify multiselect for Student attributes. `cq.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("name"));`  It is a little longer but it serves the purpose for now.

Kindly let me know if you have a better option

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `mappedby` in the Student entity, it makes Passport the owner of relation and it has to be loaded when you load the Student. 
One option is to make Student the owner like this:

Student mapping

```
 @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Passport passport;
```

Passport mapping

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="passport")
private Student student;
```

by doing this `passport_id` will be added to student table. If that is not possible for you you can either make the OneToOne relation unidirectional(Student -> Passport) or use NO_PROXY option.

Comment: Agreed and it works. However, if I want to fetch all passports, the same scenario happens since Student is now the Owner of the relationship.
It kinda looks like that we can only query in only one direction to avoid related entities to be fetched and extra queries getting fired.

Comment: right. it looks like you can only have lazy loading on one side of the one-to-one relationship.